# Creating a data frame to track variable names in other data frames

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I am trying to create a data frame in R containing indicator variables for whether or not a series of data frames contain certain variables

For instance, suppose I have these three data frames:

lombok:

```
name     color     year     attend   approval
```

bali:

```
name     color    purchases
```

papua:

```
name     color   attend
```

The resulting data frame would appear as follows:

```
dataframe   name    color    year    attend
df1         TRUE    TRUE     TRUE    TRUE
df2         TRUE    TRUE     FALSE   FALSE
df3         TRUE    TRUE     FALSE   TRUE
```

In this case, I have selected name, color, year, and attend as the four variables that I want this data frame to report on

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Get the column names after creating a `list`, `stack` to a two column data.frame and use `table`

```
lst1 <- lapply(mget(ls(pattern = "^(bali|lombok|papua)\\d*$")), names)
table(stack(lst1)[2:1]) > 0
```

-output

```
ind      approval attend color name purchases  year
  bali      FALSE  FALSE  TRUE TRUE      TRUE FALSE
  lombok     TRUE   TRUE  TRUE TRUE     FALSE  TRUE
  papua     FALSE   TRUE  TRUE TRUE     FALSE FALSE
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(tibble)
library(purrr)
mget(ls(pattern = "^(bali|lombok|papua)\\d*$")) %>% 
  map(names) %>% 
  enframe(name = 'dataframe') %>%
  unnest(value) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = value, values_from = value,
    values_fn = list(value = ~ length(.x) > 0), values_fill = FALSE)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 × 7
  dataframe name  color purchases year  attend approval
  <chr>     <lgl> <lgl> <lgl>     <lgl> <lgl>  <lgl>   
1 bali      TRUE  TRUE  TRUE      FALSE FALSE  FALSE   
2 lombok    TRUE  TRUE  FALSE     TRUE  TRUE   TRUE    
3 papua     TRUE  TRUE  FALSE     FALSE TRUE   FALSE
```

#### data

```
lombok <- data.frame(name = 'a', color = 'red', year = 2015,
     attend = 'yes', approval = 'yes')
bali <- data.frame(name = 'b', color = 'red', purchases = 10)
papua <- data.frame(name = 'c', color= 'yellow', attend = 'yes')
```

Comment: This is helpful, but I realized the problem is a bit trickier. I made edits to the question above to illustrate a couple nuances: the data frames aren't simply named "df*" and ideally I could choose which variables to include in the final dataframe

Comment: @bricevk  you can simply create a list as `list(yourdf1, yourxyz, dfex3)` etc,

Comment: another quick q: can I use the mget function for multiple groups of data frames. Suppose my dfs are bali1, bali2, bali3, lombok1, lombok2, papua1,.... In this case, the mget, paste option is helpful, but it doesn't apply across all data frames

Comment: @bricevk use `mget(ls(pattern = "^(bali|lombok|papua)\\d+$"))`

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
# Generating data.
df1 = data.frame("name" = letters, "color" = "blue", "year" = 1986, "attend" = "yes")
df2 = data.frame("name" = letters, color = "blue")
df3 = data.frame("name" = letters, color = "blue", attend = "yes")

# Defining useful list and matrix.
dfs = list(df1, df2, df3) # List storing data frames.
mat = matrix(NA, nrow = length(dfs), ncol = max(sapply(dfs, ncol)))
colnames(mat) = colnames(dfs[[which.max(sapply(dfs, ncol))]])

# Defining useful function.
store.vars = function(dta)
{
  # This function takes a data frame as input, and check if it has certain
  # variables (as defined in "mat).

  # To be used within sapply().

  return(colnames(mat) %in% colnames(dta))
}

final.df = data.frame(t(sapply(dfs, store.vars)))
rownames(final.df) = c("df1", "df2", "df3")
```

The idea is to put all the data frames into a list, and use the latter to define a matrix whose column names correspond to the names of the variables of interest.

Then, we can define `store.vars()`, which relies on the matrix defined above to scan all the data frames within a list, returning a logical vector with information about which variables are stored in each data frame. Using `store.vars()` within `sapply` yields the desired result.